# Count results in SQL statement additional row

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am trying to get 3% of total membership which the code below does, but the results are bringing me back two rows one has the % and the other is "0" not sure why or how to get rid of it ...

```
select 
    sum(Diabetes_FLAG) * 100 / (select round(count(medicaid_no) * 0.03) as percent
                                from membership) AS PERCENT_OF_Dia
from 
    prefinal
group by 
    Diabetes_Flag
```

Not sure why it brought back a second row I only need the % not the second row .

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Output:

```
        PERCENT_OF_DIA
   1    11.1111111111111
   2    0
```

Comment: You must have two different `Diabetes_Flag` values in the `prefinal` table (maybe a `NULL`?). You might need to add `WHERE Diabetes_Flag IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: How many rows do you get when you run `select distinct Diabetes_Flag from prefinal`?

Comment: Put another way... add `Diabetes_Flag` to your select so you can better understand the results.  since you're summing we can assume numeric since flag I assume 1 or 0; 0 also assumed because sum of null = null not zero and since output shows 0... assumed 1,0 in flag. 
 so `where Diabetes_Flag <> 0`

Comment: Thanks everyone . It was the nulls and '0' I had which was giving a outcome of '0'. When I put a `Where Diabetes _Flag = '1'` I got my result .

Comment: if Diabetes_Flag is numeric data type you shoudln't use the apostrophe's.  If it's not numeric; you really shouldn't be summing it.  What happens someday if someone adds a new flag. 'A' or'B' which means Type I or Type II?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(Diabetes_FLAG)*100 / (SELECT round(count(medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
                                 FROM membership) AS PERCENT_OF_Dia
FROM prefinal
WHERE Diabetes_FLAG = 1
#  GROUP BY Diabetes_Flag  # as you're limiting by the flag in the where clause, this isn't needed.
```

Comment: I like your answer best because it is explicit about the expectation that `diabetes_flag` equals 1.  But, isn't the `GROUP BY` unnecessary now?

Comment: Yes, it is unecessary; unless someone changes diabetes_flag to <> 1 and they add a new flag other than 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by` if you want one row:

```
select sum(Diabetes_FLAG)*100/( SELECT round(count(medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
 from membership) AS PERCENT_OF_Dia
from prefinal;
```

When you include `group by Diabetes_FLAG`, it creates a separate row for each value of `Diabetes_FLAG`.  Based on your results, I'm guessing that it takes on the values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure why it brought back a second row

This is how GROUP BY query works. The group by clause group data by a given column, that is - it collects all values of this column, makes a distinct set of these values and displays one row for each individual value.
Please consider this simple demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a38df/1

```
SELECT * FROM prefinal;

| Diabetes_Flag |
|---------------|
|             1 |
|             1 |
|             5 |
```

---

Usually GROUP BY column is listed in in SELECT clause too, in this way:

```
SELECT Diabetes_Flag, sum(Diabetes_Flag)
FROM prefinal
GROUP BY Diabetes_Flag;

| Diabetes_Flag | sum(Diabetes_Flag) |
|---------------|--------------------|
|             1 |                  2 |
|             5 |                  5 |
```

As you see, GROUP BY display two rows - one row for each unique value of `Diabetes_Flag` column.

---

If you remove `Diabetes_Flag` colum from SELECT clause, you will get the same result as above, but without this column:

```
SELECT sum(Diabetes_Flag)
FROM prefinal
GROUP BY Diabetes_Flag;

| sum(Diabetes_Flag) |
|--------------------|
|                  2 |
|                  5 |
```

---

So the reason that you get 2 rows is that `Diabetes_Flag` has 2 distict values in the table.